# How to change value in array column in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have

```
crew_member_ids                integer[],
```

column in table.
And want to change all entry of specific id (for example 1) to another id (for example 10)

```
{} - > {}
{1, 2} -> {10, 2}
{2, 3}  -> {2, 3}
{1} -> {10}
```

How can i do it ?

---

So far I managed only to select lines to be affected with

```
select * from initial_costs where 1 = any(crew_member_ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

tables for test

```
create table test_tabe(crew_member_ids integer[]);
insert into test_tabe values (ARRAY[3,7,4]),(ARRAY[1,8,4]),(ARRAY[1,5],ARRAY[1,1,5]),(ARRAY[3,8,20]),(ARRAY[8,10,2]);
```

```
 crew_member_ids
-----------------
 {3,7,4}
 {1,8,4}
 {1,5}
 {1,1,5}
 {3,8,20}
 {8,10,2}
```

cahnge query

```
update test_tabe set crew_member_ids[1]=10 where array_position(crew_member_ids,1)=1;
```

```
 crew_member_ids
-----------------
 {3,7,4}
 {8,10,2}
 {3,8,20}
 {10,8,4}
 {10,5}
 {10,1,5}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update initial_costs 
set crew_member_ids = array_replace(crew_member_ids, 1, 10) 
where 1 = any(crew_member_ids);
```